# Why line renderer is not working in Game view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, draw

I know Debug.Drawline is used to test in scene view. Line renderer should work in Game view right? When I tested line renderer with two spheres it worked but when I tried to do it a camera and one sphere it is not showing.Any ideas?

```
public class Lines : MonoBehaviour {


public Transform sp1;
public Transform sp2;
public Camera cam;

public GameObject Lineprefab;
LineRenderer lins;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    spawngenerator();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{

    //Debug.DrawLine(cam.transform.position, sp2.position,Color.green);
   // Debug.DrawRay(cam.transform.position, sp2.position, Color.green,100f);
    lins.SetPosition(0, sp1.position);
    lins.SetPosition(1, sp2.position);

  //  sp1.Translate(Vector3.right, Space.World);

}


void spawngenerator()
{

    GameObject newline = Instantiate(Lineprefab);
     lins = newline.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();



    }
}
```

[image]

In the above pic Line Renderer is showing in both scene and game views.Below only in scene view.Why?

[image]

[image]

[image: Working]

Comment: I guess because a line is only a "big group of points". But points have no volume -> also the line has no volume. You are looking at the line "from behind" so you actually would only see one point. Let the line start a bit above or below the camera => you should see the line again.

Comment: Can you show us the LineRenderer settings in Inspector?

Comment: At an initial guess, I'd say your scene viewpoint is too low and you're actually seeing the 'back' of the line, which doesn't actually render (back-face culling)

Comment: I tried changing the camera but i could not see the line.Let me check by adding a empty Gameobject child to camera.

Comment: @derHugo Now I am getting a line near camera to sphere when I used an empty object as a child of main camera and set the empty object as starting point.When the camera moves the point should also move right?.Similarly why cant I use this concept in AR apps.I created a empty object and made a child of ARcam.The position of the line did not change when I moved the camera in the device.

Comment: @Immersive Please look at the above comment

Comment: How come your first screenshot shows that line renderer is also showing in the Game View.?

Comment: Again, please show the Inspector

Comment: @Programmer Thats my doubt....In the second image it is not showing......As per....derHugo and Immersive  comments..it cant be seen directly from camera.So i added an empty gameobject as a child of camera and drew a line renderer between point and sphere.Now line appears in front of camera.

Comment: @Immersive added pic

Comment: @derHugo and Immersive(user). Have look at image 4 recently i added, in that when I opened unity today everything was working.Have a look at image 2 when I asked the doubt.See the camera angles I have ket almost at similar angles.In 2nd image ,line was not coming in the game view.Today when I open it again as you see in Image 4 Line is present  there in the game view.Problem with Unity??

Comment: We don't see your former camera settings so we can't confirm they stayed the same. Was the line "twisted" already before? Now it seems that it starts with a 90° twist at the camera..

Comment: @derHugo I am stupid..Now it is working because I have added a empty gameobject as child of MainCamera and this point is my starting point.If I change my starting point to lins.SetPosition(0, cam.transform.position); it wont work.

Comment: You may be inexperienced, but you are **not** stupid ;) We are glad you are figuring it out!

Comment: @derHugo The line isn't "twisted." Line renderer is a camera-facing billboard. It will always (attempt to) face the camera so that it appears to have a uniform thickness as the camera moves around it. The orientation when it's moving away from the camera will be the one that lets it on average face towards the camera. In this case, the camera's slightly to one side.

Comment: please look at the video.....will get a better understanding . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukZwEMe4Dag

Answer (score 1):

## Line Renderer has no thickness

As your line (from the camera's perspective) is parallel with the viewing angle, there is no orientation of the line that would cause it to be more than 0 pixels in size (think about it like looking dead-on the end of a piece of perfectly flat paper).

You probably want to move the camera end of your line down *below* your camera's actual location, how much below is going to depend on your project's needs and your own preferences.

Comment: Please have a look at my comment above